# C# HTML Agility Pack XPath Issues

Tags: c#, html, parsing, xpath, html-agility-pack

I will be honest I am very new to HTML Agility Pack, however I have hit a stump in the road. My goal is to parse some data out of a html page, but when iterate through all of the divs I need to and its time to pull data from each div it keeps checking the whole document instead of just inside the div.  I am sorry if this is a dumb question, I come from regex and am having issues and a lot of questions regarding this for parsing HTML. (LOL I used to parse HTML with regex). Another thing, if you guys would be so kind as too post below sites you'd recommend for helping me learn HTML Agility that would be fantastic!

**EDIT :** 
I forgot to mention, below when I select individual nodes I did try // instead of the ., but had no luck at all...

**EDIT 2 :**
I removed the html page because I know for a fact I'm able to access the data, but the issue is I am wondering how do instead of searching the whole document, search only in that element

This is The Code Below, and Below That Is The HTML I Am Parsing!

```
// GRAB DAILY BULLETIN
foreach (HtmlNode HN_POST in HD.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='newspostitem']")) 
{
    HtmlNode HN_POST_TITLE = HN_POST.SelectSingleNode(".div[@class='newsposttitle']");
    HtmlNode HN_POST_DATE = HN_POST.SelectSingleNode(".div[@class='newspubdate']");
    HtmlNode HN_POST_NOTES = HN_POST.SelectSingleNode(".div[@class='newspostnotes']");
    string FINAL = string.Format("Title - {0} | Date - {1} | Body - {2}", HN_POST_TITLE.InnerText, HN_POST_DATE.InnerText, HN_POST_NOTES.InnerText);
    FINAL = FINAL.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
    FINAL = FINAL.Replace("\r", string.Empty);
    FINAL = FINAL.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
    MAIN_LISTBOX.Items.Add(FINAL);
}
```

Comment: @mok Sorry, I am not the best writer or public speaker known to man. I tend to ramble and talk about in necessary things for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectNodes()` and `SelectSingleNode()` accept [XPath version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expression as parameter. You can learn XPath separately by following some of many tutorials on the internet, and use one of many online XPath tester to quickly run & test your XPath.

Now, for this specific question, `.div` is not a valid XPath expression. The correct XPath to query *child element named `div` where `class` attribute value equals "newsposttitle"* from current context element is either of the following :

```
./div[@class='newsposttitle']
div[@class='newsposttitle']
```